# Stack Exchange в видеоформате с @Марк Из и @Nick Volynkin [ссылка на запись]

Tags: предложение

С радостью спешу сообщить, что в ближайший понедельник (24–го апреля) в 17:26 по московскому времени состоится первый выпуск видеочата, в котором мы познакомимся с:

- [@Марк Из](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1067/), модератор сообщества Русский язык;
- [@Nick Volynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin), модератор сообщества Stack Overflow на русском.

Видео доступно здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yq6kUTfJxhc. Вы сможете задать свои вопросы участникам диалога в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) ([альтернативный чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/) для сообщества Русский язык). Обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky`, чтобы я мог своевременно отреагировать на вопрос и задать его ребятам. Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос к участникам мне на почту заранее (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com).

С нетерпением ждем вас!